# $(a+c)(b+d)=1$, $a,b,c,d \in R^{+}$. Prove that $\frac{a^3}{b+c+d} + \frac{b^3}{a+c+d} + \frac{c^3}{a+b+d} + \frac{d^3}{a+b+c} \geq \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: inequality

$(a+c)(b+d)=1$, $a,b,c,d \in R^{+}$. Prove that

$$\frac{a^3}{b+c+d} + \frac{b^3}{a+c+d} + \frac{c^3}{a+b+d} + \frac{d^3}{a+b+c} \geq \frac{1}{3}$$

rather annoying that the powers of denominators and numerators are not the same and can't think of easy way to flatten them..

Comment: Start by using AM-GM, then algebraic manupilations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naive Titu also works

WTS

$$ \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3}{b+c+d} = \sum_{cyc} \frac{ a^4 } { ab+ac+ad } \geq \frac{ (\sum a^2 )^2 } { 2 ( ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+da) } \geq \frac{1}{3}.$$

This follows because

> 1. $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2  \geq \frac{ 2}{3} ( ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+da)$, and

> 2. $a^2 +b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \geq \frac{1}{2} [ (a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2] \geq (a+c)(b+d) = 1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Use holders inequality

> $$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3}{b+c+d}\right)(1+1+1+1)\left(\sum_{cyc} b+c+d\right)\ge {\left(\sum_{cyc} a\right)}^3$$

> Apply AM-GM inequality :$$a+b+c+d\ge 2\sqrt{(a+c)(b+d)}$$ to finish

Answer (score 1):

A direct application of C-S and AM-GM works here. We have:
$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \dfrac{a^3}{b+c+d} \right) \left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} a(b+c+d)\right) \geq \left(\sum_{\text{cyc} }a^2 \right)^2.$$

It thus suffices to prove that

$$\dfrac{\left(\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyc} }a^2 \right)^2}{\left(\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyc}} a(b+c+d)\right) } \geq \dfrac{1}{3}.$$

Note that $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab, a^2+d^2 \geq 2ad, b^2+c^2 \geq 2bc, c^2+d^2 \geq 2cd.$ Thus, $2a^2+2b^2+2c^2+2d^2 \geq  2(ab+ad+bc+cd) = 2(a+c)(b+d)=2$. This gives us  $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \geq 1.$ It remains for us to prove that

$$
3\left(\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyc} }a^2 \right) \geq \left(\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyc}} a(b+c+d)\right) = 2ab+2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd+2cd.
$$
But this is just a simple application of AM-GM, and we are done.